# How to enable right to left support in adobe aem text component?

Tags: aem

I need to enable right to left language support in AEM text component. I could google that page should contain `<html dir="rtl"....>` and I assume there is something that needs to be done on AEM as well.

Any help?

Answer (score 1):

When you have to implement RTL (right-to-left) functionality in your website it is not only the front-end that has to work in a RTL-way. Also the author-interface should work as much as possible RTL, because that is what the author expects.

**Page-Template**

When designing your page-component your  element should contain the “dir”-attribute with the value of rtl.

I would like you to go through these  articles:-

Link:- http://blog.globalizationpartners.com/adobe-experience-manager.aspx

//Example to convert content from english to Arabic

Link:- http://blogs.adobe.com/experiencedelivers/experience-management/rtl-adobe-cq5-aem/

// This article tells about how template, RTE, Dialogs need modification.

Link:- https://adobeaemtherightway.wordpress.com/2014/05/02/website-globalization-and-localization-best-practices/

//Specialized Layout Requirements

Languages such as Arabic and Hebrew are read right-to-left (RTL). Often times, layouts and imagery from a site’s master branch are not designed with these special language requirements in mind. For example, text within a background image requires sufficient space in the image to safely incorporate the copy and is usually displayed at one end of the image, as seen below.

**Reference Posts:-**

1. **http://help-forums.adobe.com/content/adobeforums/en/experience-manager-forum/adobe-experience-manager.topic.html/forum__ntwc-do_we_have_anybuilt.html**
2. **http://help-forums.adobe.com/content/adobeforums/en/experience-manager-forum/adobe-experience-manager.topic.html/forum__fccj-hi_all_i_havea.html**

I hope this would be helpful to you.

Thanks and Regards

Kautuk Sahni

([Adobe AEM Forums](http://lp-forums.adobe.com/content/adobeforums/en/experience-manager-forum/adobe-experience-manager.html))

Comment: Most of those links are dead now :(